# How do I inspect the contents of tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to train my tensorflow graph over a set of data repeatedly, and I think [`tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/inputs/numpy_input_fn) might be what I'm looking for. I find the distinction between batch sizes, repeats, epochs and iterators to be incredibly confusing, so I started trying to inspect the contents of my datasets to try to figure out what's actually going on. However, whenever I try to to do this my program just hangs.

Here is the smallest test case I came up with to reproduce this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy

class TestMock(tf.test.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        inputs = numpy.array(range(10))
        targets = numpy.array(range(10,20))

        input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
            x=inputs,
            y=targets,
            batch_size=1,
            num_epochs=2,
            shuffle=False)

        print input_fn()
        with self.test_session() as sess:
            # sess.run(input_fn()[0]) # it'll hang if I run this
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.test.main()
```

This program outputs

```
(<tf.Tensor 'fifo_queue_DequeueUpTo:1' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>, <tf.Tensor 'fifo_queue_DequeueUpTo:2' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>)
```

Which seems reasonable, but as soon as I try to run that `sess.run` line, my program freezes and I have to kill the process. What am I doing wrong here?

What I want to do is make sure that the data I'm feeding into my process is actually what I think it is, but I don't think I can do that without the ability to inspect the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the above print statements we can infer that `input_fn` returns `queue ops`, we need to run them using [`start_queue_runners` and `Coordinator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/threading_and_queues):

```
 features_op, labels_op = input_fn()
 with tf.Session() as sess:
     # initialise and start the queues.
     sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

     coordinator = tf.train.Coordinator()
     _ = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coordinator)

    print(sess.run([features_op, labels_op]))

    #[array([0]), array([10])]
```

Comment: Cheers for that